# If A and B are selected within same dropdown, how do I disable C?

Tags: jquery, html, css, highcharts

I have created a multiple drop down menu. How would I go about disabling option "C" when "A" and "B" are selected simultaneously? Also, is there a way to initialize a button that would return the selected value to "-Gender-" and reload the default chart? If you could provide a fiddle example that would be fantastic!

```
<select id="list" name="list" multiple="multiple">
<option select disabled>-Gender-</option>
<option value="A">Female</option>
<option value="B">Male</option>
<option value="C">Both</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a quick example...basically in the jQuery function you need to check which options are selected and then execute the disable logic...this is a template:

https://jsfiddle.net/6kdthxgr/3/

```
const list = $('#list');
const both = list.find('option:last-child');

list.on('change', () => {
  if (list.find('option:selected').length === 2 &&
    !both.prop('selected')) {
    both.prop("disabled", true);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you Timmerz!

Comment: You are welcome. I think a better solution here is to not use a multiple select box. Simply use a single with a label of Gender and the options Male, Female, Both.